# Sum of the values of the 10 cells above me?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, worksheet-function

I'd like a formula for Google Sheets that will return the sum of the values of the ten cells above the current cell.

That is, if I'm on `C31`, I want the equivalent of `=SUM(C20:C30)`. However, I want something that will work independently of the current cell.

Comment: if you copy-paste your formula, this will "move" the formula (even if you copy it to any other cell)

Comment: @JMax Indeed, I realized this a while later. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @jmax please add that solution as an answer so Xeon06 can mark this question answered

Comment: @Raystafarian: ok. Done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, if you **copy-paste your formula**, this will "move" the formula (even if you copy it to any other cell).

This is the **same behavior as Excel**. Note that you can use the `$` too to keep either the column (`=$A1`) or the row (`=A$1`) or both (`=$A$1`) .

Answer (score 3):

This will do:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-11;COLUMN();4) &":"& ADDRESS(ROW()-1;COLUMN();4)))
```

Just paste it any cell you like and it will sum 10 cells above it, with no changes to the value.

The `ADDRESS` function returns **a string** with the *name reference* of a cell. We join two references with a **":"** between them, giving us **a string** like **"B5:B15"**. We them feed the `INDIRECT` function with this string and it will convert the string to a **internal reference**. Them we feed this **reference** to the `SUM` function and there you go.

Beware of the ";" chars separating the parameters of the function. I'm using Brazilian Portuguese spreadsheet and the separator is the ";", but it may vary depending on the locale of the sheet. In US I think they use commas (","), so if it gives you any error, try switching ";" for ",".

Answer (score 1):

A simplified version of [@diego nunes](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/21132/diego-nunes)' A:

```
=sum(offset(indirect(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),-10,,10))
```

This can be dragged around and work anywhere there are ten or more rows above.

However, as suggested by [@JMax](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/11610/jmax) something like `=sum(a1:a10)` if written in A11 can be copy and pasted and (other than in the top ten rows) will automatically adjust to suit, so copied from A11 to say C14 would become:

```
  =sum(c4:c13)
```

(drag it however and it stays `=sum(a1:a10)`).

[SUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669)
[OFFSET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379)
[INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377)
[ADDRESS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308)
[ROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316)
[COLUMN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093373)

Answer (score 0):

**try:**

```
=SUM(QUERY(SORT(C2:C30; ROW(C2:C30)*ISNUMBER(C2:C30); 0); "select * limit 10"))
```

this is basically based on a false calculation where **`ROW`** number gets multiplied by the number (**`ISNUMBER`**) in the cell to find out where is the last number in a given range **`C2:C30`**. an output is then mirrored with **`SORT`** so last value becomes first from the top and then **`QUERY`** takes it all and outputs only **`10`** rows/values that are passed into **`SUM`**

[image]

**as seen from the image, this solution takes the sum from:**

- column **B** sums numbers: **`6, 1, 5, 7, 8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 45`**
- column **C** sums numbers: **`5, 3, 2, 5, 7, 9, 8, 5, 4, 1`**
- column **D** sums numbers: **`1, 8, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 9, 2`**

Answer (score 0):

**try:**

```
=SUM(OFFSET(C2; MAX(ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(C2:C30)*--(C2:C30<>"")))-11; ; 10))
```

again based on a false calculation where **`ROW`** number gets multiplied by the cell that isn't empty **`C2:C30<>""`** in order to find out where is the last entry in a given range **`C2:C30`**. then **`ARRAYFORMULA`** generates list of values which are filtered by **`MAX`** to catch all errors (like **`25 * x`**) and then reverse **`OFFSET`** is used from a starting point/cell **C2** where is the beginning of the list, which is then restricted by last 10 values with **`-11, , 10`** and passed into **`SUM`** formula.

[image]

**as seen from the image, this solution takes the sum from:**

- column **B** sums numbers: **`6, 1, 5, 7, 8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 45`**
- column **C** sums numbers: **`5, x, 3, 2, x, 5, 7, 9, 8, 5`**
- column **D** sums numbers: **`1, 8, 1, empty cell, 1, 2, 2, empty cell, 2, 1`**

Answer (score 0):

**try:**

```
=SUM(INDEX(C2:C30; MATCH(99999; C2:C30)-9):
     INDEX(C2:C30; MATCH(99999; C2:C30)))
```

this solution is based on a search for fake number **`99999`** in the range **`C2:C30`** and unless that specific number is not provided, there is no **`MATCH`** so 2 **`INDEX`** lists are generated while one of them is slightly offset by two rows **`-9`** which kind off negates all the values leaving only last 10 cells to be calculated by **`SUM`** formula.

[image]

**as seen from the image, this solution takes the average from:**

- column **B** sums numbers: **`6, 1, 5, 7, 8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 45`**
- column **C** sums numbers: **`5, x, 3, 2, x, 5, 7, 9, 8, 5`**
- column **D** sums numbers: **`1, 8, 1, empty cell, 1, 2, 2, empty cell, 2, 1`**